# ios-sim launch Error=ExecutableTwiddleFailed, ErrorDescription=Failed to chmod file-No such file or directory

Tags: ios, cordova, ios-simulator

I am new to using `ios-sim` command to directly run an iOS app file in the simulator.

I have installed `ios-sim` following [this](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim) link. But when I fire the following command to run the app in simulator:

`ios-sim launch /Users/path/Desktop/myApp.es.app`

the simulator starts and I get the following error and then the simulator stops:

```
    Session could not be started: Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)" 
UserInfo=0x7fcd59506e90 {Error=ExecutableTwiddleFailed, 
ErrorDescription=Failed to chmod 
file:///Users/path/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/88D95C8E-DE0E-4687-9FA5-
990A45E3BBB4/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.containermanagerd/Temp/Bundle/Application/B025F33F-F9F3-4273-9D72-
D824FCD2E508/myApp.es.app/myApp.es : No such file or directory}
```

Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem. You can check to see if the file is there by using Finder:

1. Locate your .app directory
2. Right-click > Show Package Contents
3. You should see a unix executable file within that directory with the same name as the .app directory.

In my case I was using Cordova to build my project. I was then trying to use ios-sim to run a build that was located under platforms/ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator when I should have been using the build located in platforms/ios/build/emulator/